# Spring Integration - Wait till finishes processing file

Tags: spring, spring-integration

MyHandler class takes about 10-20 seconds (approximately) to process a huge 200MB csv/txt file. If I drop a file in the'my.test.dir' directory, MyHandler keeps picking the same file multiple times. To avoid this, I set prevent-duplicates to false. But I might get a file with the same file name after some time. It's not picking up files with the same name later. Please suggest, how to handle this scenario?  MyHandler has to wait until it finishes processing the file.

```
<bean id="test-file-bean" class="com.test.MyHandler"/>
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter
        id="test-adapter-inbound"
        directory="${my.test.dir}"
        channel="test-file-channel"
        filter="test-file-filter"
        prevent-duplicates="false" auto-startup="true"
        auto-create-directory="true">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="5"/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int:service-activator
        input-channel="test-file-channel" ref="test-file-bean" method="handleFlow"/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` to prevent duplicates, but pass those which timestamp has been changed.

See more info in docs : https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/file.html#file-reading.

Over there you also can find a `ChainFileListFilter` if you need to combine with your own.